# MySql Query for Users that are Friends and Non Friends of current user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, a user's table and a friends table.

```
users
__________
user_id p.k
username

friends
__________
from_user
to_user
status ENUM('1', '2') //1 for sent/pending, 2 for accepted
primary key('from_user', 'to_user') // both also reference user_id
```

I'm relatively new to MySQL and have been trying to create a search query with the wildcard characters %% that will search based on the username and return rows of usernames, user_id, and status of people that are both friends and non friends to the current user in that order with a limit of 10. I would greatly appreciate any help and guidance on this matter. Below is what I have so far.

```
SELECT Users.user_id, Users.username, Friends.status 
FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN
Friends ON
    Users.user_id IN Friends.to_user, Friends.from_user AND
    'id of user' IN Friends.to_user, Friends.from_user
WHERE
```

Comment: @Cristik I haven't gotten a full query working, I'm a newbie so I'm not really sure on how to fully execute a query like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to get the friends links:

```
select uf.user_id, uf.username, f.status
from users u
join friends f on u.user_id = f.from_user
join users uf on f.to_user = uf.user_id
where u.username like '%teddy%' and f.status = 2
LIMIT 10;
```

and this to get all the possible links, friends, sent/pending and not friends:

```
 select uf.user_id, uf.username, f.status
    from users u
    left join friends f on u.user_id = f.from_user
    left join users uf on f.to_user = uf.user_id
    where u.username like '%teddy%'
    LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I tried it and changed the phrase to a username I have saved but I don't get anything back

Comment: Do you have data in the 2 tables? because in the query you paste in the question you use left join.... If i'm not friend of someone on you're data i have a record on the table friends with the status 'not friend'?

Comment: your second query works great but is there any way to rework it so it only returns 3 fields: user_id, username, and status of a person related to the current user without returning the current user in the query?

Comment: Just remove the fields you don't want. Or add others you need.